# How to allow pop-ups in firefox? (used from selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

When using Selenium, Firefox is disabling pop-ups even on websites where it is explicitly told to allow them. Disabling the pop-up blocker entirely does not fix it.

Version: Firefox 80.0.1 (64-bit)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tt seems that it was caused by an old version of geckodriver not working with the latest version of firefox (which had auto-upgraded).

Solution is to upgrade geckodriver or to downgrade firefox.

Details [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1771).